# mysql query seems to be error.can i select the updated column with one query

Tags: mysql, error-handling

There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unclosed quote @ 173
STR: "

```
update voucher_nos 
set (select voucher_type as points from vouchers where id='1') = points+1 
where company_id = '24' 
      and finance_year='01/01/2014-01/01/2015';



update voucher_nos 
set (select voucher_type as points from vouchers where id='1') = points+1 
where company_id = '24' 
       and finance_year='01/01/2014-01/01/2015'";
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(select voucher_type as points from vouchers
>               where id='1') = points+1 w' at line 1

helps will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
and finance_year='01/01/2014-01/01/2015'";
```

You have an unneccesary " at the end here, which is probably causing the Syntax error.

--

The second problem is that the first part of a SET statement should be a column name, not a value (or a query which returns one). But I'm not sure how to fix that unless you explain a bit more what you're trying to accomplish.